# I hit a curb hard and I popped the tire and the wheel is scratched? Besides the popped tire can the wheel run again?

Tags: wheels, lincoln, navigator

I hit a curb hard while I was turning in order to get through a gate. This popped the wheel and left a hole.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you have to check for is if the wheel is still true. As long as it runs true and isn't cracked, it should most likely be just fine. The scratches look cosmetic. In order to check this you can possibly jack up the car and spin the wheel with it on a hub. The better bet is to take it to a tire store, have the popped tire taken off, then have it spun where you can see it directly.

**NOTE:** Just like tires, it's hard to say over the internet with a couple of small format images to guide the way. Take it to a respectable tire place and have them give you guidance.

Answer (score 0):

That rim is badly dented.  You will have vibration on the highway, which can damage the wheel bearing.  Replace it.